# get user from established mysql connection

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have established an MySQL connection using `MySQLdb` python library. Due to the fact that initial connection is taking place in totally different place I would like to get the username from a given `MySQLdb.connections.Connection` object.

After some study of source code and some tests I didn't find any way to get the username.

```py
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

db = MySQLdb.connect(
  host=host, 
  user=user, 
  passwd=passwd, 
  db=dbname, 
  use_unicode=True, 
  charset="utf8mb4", 
  cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor
)
try:
  print(db.user)
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

Output:

```py
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Is there any way to get this kind of attribute?

**Versions:**

MySQLdb: `1.4.2.post1`

Python: `2.7`

Comment: Personally, I would not use a library that hasn't been updated for 5 years.  However, you should be able to get a `cursor` from `connection` and run some raw SQL, such as `"select USER();"`.

Comment: @FiddleStix you are totally right. Switching from `MySQLdb` to a more active module is necessary but migration process is taking more time than expected :/
Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
db.query('SELECT CURRENT_USER();')
r = db.store_result()
r = r.fetch_row()
print(r[0][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all.

> AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'user'

You can verify this by executing this piece of code:

```
from MySQLdb import Connection

x = dir(Connection)
print(x)
```

It will print the attributes of the `Connection` object. The output looks like this:

```
['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__kwdefaults__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Therefore, there is not a `user` attribute.

In order to get the current user you can do what @Tamoor Salah-U-Din suggested.
I hope this helps